# Plural adjectives of plural nouns: "Device terminals" VS "devices terminals"

Tags: adjectives, singular-vs-plural, comprehension, possessive-adjectives

My mother tongue is Spanish. I'm trying to complete a legend for a technical drawing I'm doing. The text I'm writing doesn't have a context that makes it clear what I want to say. I want to put a symbol in my legend and specify that symbol is used to represent the many terminals of many devices.

1. Can I say "Devices Terminals" ?
2. If I say "Device Terminals" how do English native speakers know I'm talking about multiple devices multiple terminals as opposed to 1 device multiple terminals?

While this makes perfect sense in Spanish : "Terminales de dispositivos" the only way around this I have found is to write "Terminals for devices"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In English, adjectives don't take any endings to represent number, gender, or case, so "devices terminals" is not correct.

When we are using a noun as an adjective, we always take the singular form, but it represents a general property of the thing being described, not an association to an actual object. So the phrase "device terminals" doesn't refer to "a device", but rather to "associated with devices, in general".

If all you're trying to say is that these are terminals for *devices*, rather than terminals for something else, then "device terminals" does the job fine, whatever number of terminals and devices you have.

Your suggestion of "terminals for devices" is fine, but this is still slightly ambiguous - is *each terminal* for multiple devices, or do they go in pairs of one terminal and one device. If you *really* need to be specific for some reason, you might need to reword your sentence to say something like "a terminal for each device".

Answer (score 1):

As you imply, English does not have a concept of singular vs. plural adjectives. As a technical person myself, I actually think "Terminals for devices" is a good solution. It does not sound awkward to me at all, and it's probably the simplest way to convey the point you are trying make, that the terminals can be for multiple devices.